# Место хранения статических локальных переменных зависит от уровня оптимизации?

Tags: c++, linux, c, static, elf

Иногда в Compiler Explorer одни и те же статические локальные переменные функций показываются до функций, их использующих (-O0), а иногда - после, в конце ассемблера (-O2). Означает ли это, что они могут хранится в разных местах экзешника при разных оптимизациях? Или это просто неопределённый порядок отображения godbolt-а, никак не связанный с реальным кодом?

[Пример](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGEgKykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBIAzKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BASlpGQKh4VEssfFcSXaYDplCBEzEBNk%2BflyB1bUC9Y0ExZExcYm2DU0tue0jvf2l5YkAlLaoXsTI7BxhBADU0Y0Q81smAOxWGgCCW5dbCg2OyFtoDDeYqsnEW5tbqib%2BVv4AIocEoDjhYuKQtmYIUkttItv5jv8TAlTmcTOcrh9BFsAJ5AwEaZGozH8d4QJheIgfLYgL4HUHoi6Yq546zIwF4ImMzGIxncq7ETAEFYMXFc868iXnT4sJhhfaHE78y6C4XEUW7Yj7cVoo7/DiLWicfy8PwcLSkVCcNxsyzXZarTCHMwJHikAiaA2LADWIEk/gAdP4ABwJfwATgAbGYpP4uFwNNIjRxJLwWCB/BpSGaLVaOLwFCAsx7zQbSHBYEg0CxknQ4uRKNXa/R4sAFMxkgoEKgCKQsAA3PBrABqeEwAHcAPLJRicN00WgEOKFiDRT2kaJhRo4ue8TfMYg4yfRbQ1Etu6tsQSThi0HelvuYaJeYBuMS0QvcXhYWVGcQP/BBVqftME/C0XhqSl1gtTZMGTC1aDwaJiG3DwsHXAhiDwdMv0WKgDDbUcJ2nWcvxkQQRDEdgpHI%2BQlDUdddHBAwjBQW0bEQ6JC1gZg2BAIVaFIED4kwrwGG9RYIF49hgFQVBgHoJcbiEoZRPE%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%2B20s%2BuE9JnEkIA%3D%3D)

Comment: Надежный результат даст `nm` (или `objdump`), но думаю, что godbolt тоже не отсебятничивает.  Вообще, их расположение очевидно зависит от порядка линковки. А поскольку, в зависимости от оптимизации, переменные могут вообще выбрасываться, то можно уверенно предположить, что они могут размещаться в разных  местах слинкованного модуля.

Comment: @avp я думал, что статические переменные лежат в отдельном сегменте экзешника. А значит весь этот сегмент передвигается относительно названий функций? Или названия функций тоже в нём?

Comment: @avp да https://godbolt.org/ по сути и использует эти утилиты; думаю, в плане правильности символов у него проблем нет, только если он потом как-то неправильно сортирует их. У меня 1 простой файл с определением static переменной в 1 функции. Она не выбрасывается и проблем с линковкой не может быть (в принципе с линковкой не должно быть проблем для статической локальной переменной)

Comment: @avp добавил пример в вопрос. Мне непонятно, от чего зависит порядок отображения в CE и почему он меняется при O0/O2.

Comment: С одним файлом разницы при ликовке, конечно, не будет. Почему при O0/O2 порядок меняется? Могу лишь предположить, что распределение памяти происходит тут на разных этапах трансляции. Убедиться в этом можно только поисследовав код компилятора (или если вдруг тут есть кто-то из его разработчиков -))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не знаю, что показывают окошки по вашей ссылке, а `objdump` в обоих случаях покаывает, что символ `_ZZ3barvE1x` размещён в `.rodata` по смещению`0x2010`.

Скомпилировал ваш пример компилятором g++ v11.4.0 со всеми вариантами [ключа `-O`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html):

```bash
for o in 0 1 2 3 s fast g; do g++ -O$o main.cpp -o exe.$o; done
```

Получил

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 15848 Oct 16 15:35 exe.0*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 15848 Oct 16 15:35 exe.1*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 15848 Oct 16 15:35 exe.2*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 15808 Oct 16 15:35 exe.3*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 17320 Oct 16 15:35 exe.fast*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 15848 Oct 16 15:35 exe.g*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 15848 Oct 16 15:35 exe.s*
```

Нашел местоположение символа `_ZZ3barvE1x` в сгенерированных бинарниках:

```sh
for f in exe*; do echo $f; objdump -t $f | grep _ZZ3barvE1x; done
```

Результат

```
exe.0
0000000000002010 l     O .rodata        0000000000000014              _ZZ3barvE1x
exe.1
0000000000002010 l     O .rodata        0000000000000014              _ZZ3barvE1x
exe.2
0000000000002010 l     O .rodata        0000000000000014              _ZZ3barvE1x
exe.3
exe.fast
exe.g
0000000000002010 l     O .rodata        0000000000000014              _ZZ3barvE1x
exe.s
0000000000002010 l     O .rodata        0000000000000014              _ZZ3barvE1x
```

- `-O3` и `-Ofast` оптимизировали `bar()::x` нафиг,
- во всех остальных случаях этот символ находится в секции `.rodata` по адресу `0x2010`.

**Местоположение `rodata`**

```sh
objdump -h exe.0 | head -5; for f in exe*; do echo $f; objdump -h $f | grep rodata; done
```

```
exe.0:     file format elf64-x86-64

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
exe.0
 15 .rodata       00000024  0000000000002000  0000000000002000  00002000  2**4
exe.1
 15 .rodata       00000024  0000000000002000  0000000000002000  00002000  2**4
exe.2
 15 .rodata       00000024  0000000000002000  0000000000002000  00002000  2**4
exe.3
 15 .rodata       00000004  0000000000002000  0000000000002000  00002000  2**2
exe.fast
 15 .rodata       00000004  0000000000002000  0000000000002000  00002000  2**2
exe.g
 15 .rodata       00000024  0000000000002000  0000000000002000  00002000  2**4
exe.s
 15 .rodata       00000024  0000000000002000  0000000000002000  00002000  2**4
```

Секция `rodata` во всех файлах находится по смещению `0x2000` и во всех случаях загружается по виртуальному адресу `0x2000`

**Содержимое секции `rodata`**

```sh
objdump -s -j .rodata exe.0
```

```
exe.0:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .rodata:
 2000 01000200 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
 2010 01000000 02000000 03000000 04000000  ................
 2020 05000000
```

Как видно, по виртуальному адресу `0x2010` находится массив `[1,2,3,4,5]`

В файлах, собранных с ключами `-O3` и `-Ofast`, константа `bar()::x` оптимизирована нафиг, поэтому в этих файлах `rodata` гораздо короче:

```
exe.3:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .rodata:
 2000 01000200                             ....            

exe.fast:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .rodata:
 2000 01000200                             ....
```

**Итого**

Во всех случаях константа `bar()::x` находится в одном и том же месте бинарника. Либо не находится вовсе ))

Comment: Если выключить фильтрацию директив, то видно что в обоих случаях метка `bar()` находится в секции text, а метка `bar()::x` - в секции rodata. Меняется не местоположение символа внутри секции, а порядок самих секций. Вопрос в том, меняется ли порядок секций в файле, или это придурь компилятора в режиме листинга?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Положение секции `rodata` не меняется. `objdump -h` показывает, что секция `rodata` во всех бинарниках на одном и том же месте `15 .rodata       00000024  0000000000002000  0000000000002000  00002000  2**4` (смещение 0x2000 относительно начала файла). Правда, такое фиксированное положение `rodata` возникло благодаря тому, что секция `text` в этом игрушечном примере почти не меняется в размерах, от 0x10a до 0x160. Укладывается в 4кб между 0x1000 и 0x2000. Если бы флуктуация размера была больше, то положение секция `rodata` могло бы меняться от файла к файлу.

Comment: Тогда осталось проверить ключ `-S` у `gcc` и вопрос с виновником будет решён...